# Rearrange plot of pedigree in package kinship2

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a small pedigree `ped` (full structure below) using the package `kinship2`. The current plot behavior is to duplicate a node in order to break out a subpedigree (shown with the dotted line).

I would like to modify the pedigree or plot parameters in a way that would prevent node `ID10` in the example from splitting off. I have tried modifying the order of IDs in the pedigree and varying the `width` argument in the plot call, but have not been able to find a combination that results in the desired output.

```
library(kinship2)

head(as.data.frame(ped))
#     id dadid momid    sex
#  1 ID1   ID6  ID15 female
#  2 ID2  ID11  ID10 female
#  3 ID3     0     0   male
#  4 ID4   ID5   ID3 female
#  5 ID5     0     0 female
#  6 ID6   ID8  ID10 female

plot(ped, col=c(rep(1,9),2,rep(1,5))) #color the misbehaving node red
```

[image: undesired pedigree]
Data:

```
dput(ped)
structure(list(id = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6", 
"ID7", "ID8", "ID9", "ID10", "ID11", "ID12", "ID13", "ID14", 
"ID15"), findex = c(6, 11, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 11, 0, 
13, 0), mindex = c(15, 10, 0, 3, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 9, 0, 
7, 0), sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), class = "pedigree")
```

Comment: Why are your gender symbols reversed, e.g. ID1 is listed as female but shown as a box?  I've completed your pedigree and plotted it.  ID10 is shown only once, as a box which is what he must be for the `sex` column to be correct in your pedigree.

Comment: Ah, yes I had the sexes reversed. When I fixed that I also obtained the desired output. Thank you!